# Я создал БД и сгенерировал Ее в сущности. Я могу непосредственно пользоваться этими сущностями?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Я создал БД и сгенерировал Ее в сущности, т.е. у меня сформирровались классы из этой самой базы данных. Я могу непосредственно пользоваться этими сущностями? или лучше сначало надо создать отдельный класс и уже из этого класса присваивать значения из сущности?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете пользоваться этими сгенерированными классами. Они собственно для этого и есть.

Answer (score 2):

Пользоваться, конечно, можете. Но тут есть один нюанс - они генерируются автоматически, и из-менять их весьма нежелательно. Об этом даже есть специальное предупреждение в файлах каждой такой модели, которое гласит:

> This code was generated from a template.
>   Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
>   Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.

То есть, если вам вдруг понадобится (а вам, вероятнее всего, рано или поздно понадобится) как-то их изменять/дополнять, то все подобные изменения будут затерты после следующего обновления моделей из базы. Это довольно неприятно.

Тут есть как минимум два возможных выхода:

Первый. Сгенерированные сущности являются partial-классами, соответственно, их можно расширять, используя для этого другие файлы, в которых будет описаны "недостающие" части вашей сущности. 
Достоинства: нет необходимости заводить еще какие-то классы, а можно сразу использовать имеющиеся
Недостатки: расширять их таким образом, конечно, можно, а вот изменять эти сущности затруднительно. Если вас чем-то не устроят автоматически сгенерированные свойства в этих классах, которые вы бы хотели изменить или удалить, тут снова придется столкнуться с проблемой опасности ручного изменения автоматически генерируемого кода.

Второй способ. Вы можете написать свои собственные модели, которые потом будете как-то конвертировать в сущности Entity Framework'а и обратно. 
Достоинства: В этом случае ваши модели могут быть более гибкими, вы можете как угодно изменять их по своему усмотрению и как угодно проецировать сущности из EF на эти модели. 
Недостатки: необходисмость создания новых классов и определения правил конвертации этих классов в сущности EF и обратно

Comment: Т.е.желательно создвать классы отдельно все таки? а потом свойствам из этих классов присваеивать свойства сгенерированных сущностей я так понял?

Comment: @Ildarik07 можно сделать свои классы и использовать какой нибуть mapper для автоматического преобразования туда и обратно

Comment: @Ildarik07 нет не правильно. Это больше зависит от ваших предпочтений и от ситуации в каждом конкретном случае